# How to give extra arguments for the Python itertools.ifilter function?

Tags: python, ifilter, python-itertools

In python I have the following function:

```
def is_a_nice_element(element, parameter):
    #do something
    return True or False
```

Now I would like to filter a list with this function as predicate, giving a fixed parameter. Python has the itertools.ifilter function, but I can't figure out how to pass the parameter. Is this possible? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a `lambda`:

```
itertools.ifilter(lambda e: is_a_nice_element(e, 42), iterable)
```

42 is your extra argument, or whatever else you want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

I like [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) much better than `lambda`.

```
itertools.ifilter( partial(is_a_nice_element, parameter=X), iterable )
```

Comment: +1 for using 'partial', although you didn't explained why you like it better.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions use `lambda` and `functools.partial` are quite correct and directly answer your question, but I don't think they are really the ideal solution.

Using `filter`/`itertools.ifilter`/`map`/`itertools.imap` with an anonymous function is prettymuch always going to be less clear than using a generator expression or list comprehension. For example, in this case I would write the generator expression

```
(item for item in iterable if is_a_nice_element(item, constant))
```

instead of using `ifilter`. In this case the `ifilter` solution is still fairly readable, but in many cases trying to go through lots of trouble to define just the right function is not going to be as worth while as just performing the operation.

Comment: A disadvantage of doing it this way is that you can't parametrize the filter.  EG if you want to do this filtering within a function like `def find_nice_elements(filter_function=partial(is_nice, p=42)): ...`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ifilter` then parameter would need to be constant in which case you could use a default argument `parameter=something`. If you want parameter to vary, you'd need to use another method to take a dyadic predicate.

If you already have the list in hand, `ifilter` is a bit of overkill relative to the built-in [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter).

Describing what you want to accomplish would help in making a more concrete answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I need this parameter to be given there. If I wouldn't need the parameter there I wouldn't have a problem.